# Default checked true in Nebular?

Tags: angular, nebular

I am trying to make the default checked button in ngx.

In the component.ts file I am having the following script

```
options = [
  { value: 'URL', label: 'URL' , checked: true}, //checked true not working
  { value: 'UPLOAD', label: 'Upload File' },
];
```

And following is my html file

```
<nb-radio-group [(ngModel)]="option">
      <nb-radio  class='radio-button' *ngFor="let option of options" [value]="option.value">
        {{ option.label }}
      </nb-radio>
    </nb-radio-group>
```

How to make checked true at the first load in ngx?

Answer (score 1):

You can try to set in your component this.

```
ngOnInit() {
 this.option.value = 'URL'
}
```

If you wanna to set checked for { value: 'URL', label: 'URL' , checked: true};

Or use like this :

```
    <nb-radio-group [(value)]="radioGroupValue">
      <nb-radio
        [value]="'This is value 1'">
        Radio 1
      </nb-radio>
      <nb-radio
        [value]="'This is value 2'">
        Radio 2
      </nb-radio>
      <nb-radio
        [value]="'This is value 3'">
        Radio 3
      </nb-radio>
    </nb-radio-group>
```

And in you component set default value:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

    @Component({
      selector: 'your-component',
      styleUrls: ['./your-component.scss'],
      templateUrl: ['./your-component.html',
    })

    export class FormInputsComponent {
      radioGroupValue = 'This is value 2';
    }
```

Comment: Here's a consolidated example https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54343393/default-checked-true-in-nebular.

Answer (score 0):

Use the below one,

```
 <nb-radio-group [(ngModel)]="option">
      <nb-radio  class='radio-button' *ngFor="let option of options" [value]="option.value" [checked]="option.checked">
        {{ option.label }}
      </nb-radio>
 </nb-radio-group>
```

Or if you would like to select the first option. Try this

```
<nb-radio-group [(ngModel)]="option">
      <nb-radio  class='radio-button' *ngFor="let option of options;first as isFirst" [value]="option.value" [checked]="isFirst">
        {{ option.label }}
      </nb-radio>
 </nb-radio-group>
```